# IE10 frame support is disabled. Why? And how can I enable it?

Tags: asp.net, frames, internet-explorer-10

Request.Browser.Frames returns false. It should return true, because this determines if frames are supported for us, and frames are required in our application.

The problem is in an IE 10 browser (v10.0.9200.16521), on a Windows 7, 64 bit.
The webapplication is seen as a intranet website by the browser.

I tried the following already:

- I Added the website to the trusted sites, and changed security level to low (as a test)
- When the browser runs in compatibility mode, then frames are supported. But I don't want the sites to run in compatibility mode.
- Reset browser to all default values

So, how can I get Request.Browser.Frames to return true, for IE10, without running in compatibility mode?

Thanks.

Comment: This probably requires an updated browserCaps entry. There was a fix that helped other IE10 on Windows 8 issues put out a while ago. Is your web server fully patched from Windows Update?

Comment: You were right, this was not our server, but I think it was behind. The hotfix in Knaģis answer fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link for details how to fix this error (the browser identification data in ASP.NET version you are using might be obsolete):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was already busy testing this hotfix when you posted the answer, and this did fix it! 
The Request.Browser properties are not obsolete, see documentation for .net framework 4.5 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx